# Excel - publishing pivot charts to mhtml

Tags: html, excel, charts, publish, mhtml

I'm hoping someone can help with the below please....

I have created several excel dashboards across multiple sheets in the same workbook, each dashboard contains several pivot charts.

I am trying to export each dashboard into a mhtml file with autorefresh switched on each time I save the excel file.

The first few work perfectly but when I publish any more than 2 dashboards  image objects of the charts appear layered over the original pivot charts (or just slightly off them) creating blurring on the charts.  This then becomes what is published to the mhtml file.

Here are the steps I follow:

1) Select print area
2) File > Save As > mhtml
3) Save = Selection 
4) Publish
5) Item to publish = Print Area
6) Autorepublish every time this workbook is saved = Yes
7) Publish